# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDevDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio

I get this message every time I try to use the new instant run feature on Android studio 2.0 preview version. I know it is not a stable release but I expect it to at least work. Any help will be appreciated

[Error message i get in the IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzF9X.png)

Comment: same here, after update to 2.0 preview